# Issue with AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am developing an applicationthat saves some keyvalues in `SharedPrefernces`. But I want delete some key's from shared preferences on the basis of their ID at 03:00(03:00 AM) with `INTERVAL_DAY`. And by reading some blocks and `stackoverflow` answer about AlarmManager, I am trying with this code right now,

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3); 
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); 
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Intent intent = new Intent(context, ClearSharedPreferences.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", ID);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (alarmManager != null) {
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }
```

Everything is working is fine, but problem is that instead of running at 03:00 at night. `AlarmManager` is running just after 2-3 minutes as I am setting it.

So, the question is how to set an `AlarmManager` for running at specific hour of the day ?

Answer (score 0):

set Alarm like this:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

    if (calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: Why adding `DATE` ?

Comment: it will skip alarm to the next day if time lapse.